# minion Interactive authentication required

Tags: linux, raspbian, opennms

I have installed the minion packages from the deb repository and everything installed smoothly. I was following the instructions from:  https://docs.opennms.org/opennms/releases/latest/guide-install/guide-install.html#gi-install-minion-debian .
I haven't made any changes to /etc/default/minion, which may be my problem but I'm not sure.
When starting the minion service (service minion start), I get the error message below from  systemctl status minion.service:

> LIBRENMS01 minion[22076]: Starting minion (via systemctl): minion.serviceFailed to start minion.service: Interactive authentication required.

I'm not quite sure how to approach this and am starting it up as root. I have an account on the box called minion, but I'm not sure where I can use it with it's password (which I haven't even looked at).

I'd appreciate any assistance.

Thank you.

Comment: Can you please share some more details? What interesting would be, what is the version of the Minion, operating system and Java version? Do you have any errors in `/opt/minion/data/log/karaf.log`? Do you have any errors in `journalctl -u minion`?

Comment: It's likely a permission issue.  On CentOS I found I had to run the minion as root.  Edit `/etc/init.d/minion` and change `RUNAS=minion` to `RUNAS=root` and it should work